# JOptionPane.showInputDialog cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing, javac, joptionpane

I've tried my best to research this myself, but cannot get anywhere - I keep getting the same errors. I'm compiling from terminal with the javac command, and get the errors -

```
javaJOptionPane.java:1: JOptionPane is already defined in this compilation unit
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
^
javaJOptionPane.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method showInputDialog(java.lang.String)
location: class JOptionPane
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input");
                              ^
2 errors
```

for this code -

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class JOptionPane
{
    public static void main()
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Input");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Using the command "javac filename.java". Sorry if this has already been answered; I can't find it, and am rather stuck!

Comment: 1. (class JOptionPane) don't to use reserver Java word as your class name, 2. (public static void main()) should be public static void main(String[] args), 3. then you can to quite to ignore then answers here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to redefine an already defined class `JOptionPane` , just rename your class and it should be fine

```
class JOptionPaneDemo
{
     // continue
```

Also since you'd have to define this in "JOptionPaneDemo.java", you can compile and run this as

```
javac JOptionPaneDemo.java
java JOptionPaneDemo
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the compiler error, yet the program still won't run, and produces the error-
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: @PointToPoint If you have a new question, please create a new question. I think your original problem is now solved. Note that if you use an IDE, such as Eclipse, many of these problems are easier to diagnose.

Comment: @Duncan is correct, but just a suggestion check your classpath or try compiling again. This just simply means that it cant find the generated ".class" file.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll research it myself. Cheers!

Comment: Consider marking this question as answered, if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class name to something else - `JOptionTest`. You are actually confusing the *compiler* with same name. so, it looks for the method - `showInputDialog` in your class instead of in `JOptionPane` class in `JDK`

```
javac JOptionTest.java // to compile it
java JOptionTest // to run it
```